# Cannot style my navigation bar by using the navigation bar classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to make and ecommerce site by using html, and css, got a navigation bar template from bootstrap. My problem goes when i want to style the .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link classes, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'm currently learning so I'm not so experimented, also is my first time using bootstrap

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
h2{
    font-size:1.8rem;
    font-weight:600;
}
h3{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight:800;
}
h4{
    font-size:1.1rem;
    font-weight:600;
}
h5{
    font-size:1rem;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#1d1d1d;
}
h6{
    color:#d8d8d8;
}
.cash{
    color:rgb(231, 215, 66);
    font-family: 'Amita';
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.aside{
    color:rgb(255, 179, 0);
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style:italic;
}

.logo{
    width:3.5%;
    display:flex;
}

.navbar{
    font-size: 16 px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: black;
    transition:0.3s ease;
}


.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar i:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active{
    color:coral;
}

.navbar i{
    font-size:1.2rem;
    padding:0  7px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:500;
    transition:0.3s ease;

}
</pre>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amita:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title>CashCavaleria</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="cash">Cash</span><span class="aside">Cavaleria.</span></a> 
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Acasă</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Magazin</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Despre Cashcavaleria</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <i class="fal fa-search"></i>
                <i class="fal fa-shopping-bag"></i>
              </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

   









    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` ? Because as far as I can see there's nothing wrong with your code, it might just be that Bootstrap overwrites your styling because its CSS is more specified. This is a common problem with Bootstrap once you try to do custom styling.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a CSS framework that has awesome styling right out-of-the-box. It's a versatile tool during wireframing because you can just add a class here and there and you'll be all set. The downside, however, is that most of the styling that is attached to those classes have been written in such a specific way, that browsers naturally will favor Bootstrap styling over custom styling.

You see, browsers will favor more specific 'element-targeting' over more general targetting. e.g.:

`html body #wrapper ul li` is more specific than `ul li` and thus browsers will overwrite the latter with the former.

In case of Bootstrap, this leaves you with a few options:

### Option 1

Be more specific, i.e. make use of the `html body` prefix for your styling, and make sure your elements are more specifically targeted.

### Option 2

Use `!important` as a suffix for your CSS properties. This will communicate to the browser that your styling has to have top-priority over anything else that is applied to that element. However, if two CSS target statements receive the `!important` tag, browsers will still favor the more specific:

```
html body ul li{    display: none  !important;   }
     body ul li{    display: block !important;   }
<!-- result: <li> will be hidden. -->
```

Furthermore, it is usually considered bad practise to use !important so always try this as a last resort.

### Option 3

Think of new classes which you can apply to your elements. If you target a specific 'unique' class that has not styling declared anywhere else, browsers will be more likely to favor that styling - i.e. a class named `.flaviusPopaStyling` will surely not be used by Bootstrap and thus can be considered unique enough.

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.flaviusPopaStyling{
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: black;
    transition:0.3s ease;
}


.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.flaviusPopaStyling:hover,
.navbar i:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.flaviusPopaStyling.active{
    color:coral;
}
```

Make sure to add the class to your HTML as well, for instance:

```
<a class="nav-link active flaviusPopaStyling" aria-current="page" href="#">Acasă</a>
```

### Bonus option

Instead of using Classes, I personally prefer using a non-reserved attribute name called `contains`.

```
<nav contains='customNavBar' class="navbar navbar-light . . .">
```

Because, by doing so, I both add more semantic meaning to my HTML as well as use obviously unique identifiers for CSS targetting, as well as prepare my HTML to be handled by JavaScript in such a way that will never influence its styling, for instance by `toggleClass` etc. You've written that you're quite new to styling so I'll take the liberty to assume you're kind of fresh to the front-end game so it might be a bit unclear as to *why exactly* you'd want to do this. But that's a topic for a later time.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn `Css selectors Weight`:
[Css Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

In your example, there are some some `selectors` which have more weight and overrite your `custom-css` Codes. For Example if you add:

```
nav .container-fluid .navbar-nav .nav-link.active{
  color:red ;
}
```

then you overrite the current `css`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot to close the `<ul>` tag.

Second, you are using v4.1.3 for `bootstrap.min.css` but v5.0.2 for `bootstrap.min.js`. You should use the same version for all bootstrap files.

Finally, your `styles.css` should go after `bootstrap.min.css`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amita:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <!-- put this last so it can overwrite bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>CashCavaleria</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```